# Select specified columns from DataFrame (Java/Spark)

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following problem:

I've a schema(1) and a DataFrame with an other schema(2). The DataFrames schema has only one difference to the other schema, it has one more column.
Now, I want to select columns from the DataFrame, which were specified in schema(1).

Example:

```
StructType schema; //specified in constructor
DataFrame df_old; //given as parameter
DataFrame df_new = df_old.select(schema.fieldNames());
```

This won't work, because select() needs two parameter and only one is given. So, my idea was:

```
StructType schema; //specified in constructor
DataFrame df_old; //given as parameter

String[] columns = schema.fieldNames(); //get column names as string array
String   first_col = columns[0]; // get first element of string array
columns = Arrays.copyOfRange(columns, 1, columns.length); //remove first element

DataFrame df_new = df_old.select(first_col,columns);
```

I think, that this is not the best way, because copyOfRange() would cost a lot of time. Especially, if there are a lot of columns and I need to run this multiply times.

Does somebody has a better idea?

Thanks for your answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

//below code is to select specific columns from a data frame

//try this
StructType schema; //specified in constructor
DataFrame df_old; //given as parameter

```
String[] columns = schema.fieldNames(); //String type array for name of columns 
Column[] colList = new Column[columns.length]; // column type list of same length required 
for(int i=0; i<columns.length; i++){
    colList[I]=columns[i];`enter code here`
}
```

DataFrame df_new = df_old.select(colList);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).